# How to get values of the children from a element except the last one jquery?

Tags: jquery

If I have the following case:

```
<div id="Vater1">
    <div id="child1">Child 1</div>
    <div id="child2">Child 2</div>
    <div id="child3">Child 3</div>
    <div id="child4">Child 4</div>
</div>
```

And I want to get the values of all children von Vater1 except the last one, Child 4. Exist a way to do this?

Comment: `console.log($('#Vater1').find('div:not(:last)').text())` try

Comment: @Pekka `find` => `children`

Comment: its another possible answer right?i tried in fiddle it works i get `Child 1Child 2Child 3`

Comment: `console.log($('#Vater1').children(':not(:last)').text())` @Tushar

Comment: Thx very much @Pekka!

Comment: happy coding ill post it as answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [:not](https://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) with [:last](https://api.jquery.com/last-selector/) selectors.

```
$('#Vater1').children(':not(:last)').text()
```

OR

```
$('#Vater1').find('div:not(:last)').text()
```

You can try using these selectors